# Cannot seem to escape a scripted bash command. Every time wrong / incorrect output

Tags: bash, escaping

Okay, this is killing me. I understand that I have to escape double quotes and such, however I cannot get the below scripted bash command to work properly.

On the remote server the following command works as expected:

```
sed 's|EX_ROOT=/root/$SERVER|EX_ROOT="/root/$SERVER"|g'  /etc/example/config.conf
```

Result: **EX_ROOT="/root/$SERVER"**

(this is what is expecetd)

However when running the command remotely from a different server like this:

```
ssh root@$HWNODEIP "sed 's|EX_ROOT=/root/$SERVER|EX_ROOT="/root/$SERVER"|g' /etc/example/config.conf"
```

Doesn't add the double quotes. So I remembered that I have to escape the double quotes. But here I run into a wall. Whatever I try, I am not getting the expected result.

### Example 1:

```
ssh root@$HWNODEIP "sed 's|EX_ROOT=/root/$SERVER|EX_ROOT="\""/root/$SERVER"\""|g' /etc/example/config.conf"
```

Gives: **EX_ROOT="/root/"$SERVER**

($SERVER is not within the quotes)

### Example 2:

```
ssh root@$HWNODEIP "sed 's|EX_ROOT=/root/$SERVER|EX_ROOT=\"/root/\$SERVER\"|g' /etc/example/config.conf"
```

Gives: **EX_ROOT="/root/$SERVER"$SERVER**

(Close but still not the expected result)

### Expected / desired result:

```
EX_ROOT="/root/$SERVER"
```

I have no clue what I am doing wrong here. I know I am close, but really no idea. I tried a few other things as in using more quotes and trying to escape more, but all without result and now I am out of ideas...

Comment: Side note: `sed -E 's|(EX_ROOT=)(/root/$SERVER)|\1"\2"|g'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first attempt doesn't send double quotes to the remote server; they locally close and reopen your double-quoted string.

You need to escape them. Your example 2 is *close*, but you forgot to escape the dollar sign in the regular expression, so you wound up running `sed 's|EX_ROOT=/root/|EXROOT="/root/$SERVER"'` after the unset local variable `SERVER` expanded to the empty string.

```
ssh root@$HWNODEIP "sed 's|EX_ROOT=/root/\$SERVER|EX_ROOT=\"/root/\$SERVER\"|g' /etc/example/config.conf"
                                         ^
                                         |
                                 backslash here
```

---

To edit the file in-place, though, use `ed` instead of the non-standard `sed` extension `-i`.

```
printf 's|EX_ROOT=$SERVER|EX_ROOT="$SERVER"|g\nwq\n' |
    ssh root@$HWNODEIP 'ed /etc/example/config.conf'
```

Since `ed` doesn't have to read the data to edit from standard input, it can read the *script* from standard input, one command per line. The syntax is essentially the same as `sed`. Now, though, you need far less escaping, because the script is not exposed to the shell on the remote end. (If the `wq` command looks familiar, that's because `vi` is based on `ex` which is based on `ed`.)

Comment: Just one backlash.... Argh!! I thought I had tried that before, but apparently I did not. Otherwise I wouldn't have posted this. Thank you for explaining it so detailed. I will keep this in mind for the near future. Thank you kindly for helping out with your detailed answer! Highly appreciated.

Comment: Is your final goal to modify `config.conf` in place?  You want to use `ed` instead, which reads its script from standard input rather than from a command-line argument. Then you can simply write `printf 's|...|g\nwq\n' | ssh $host 'ed /etc/example/config.conf'`, *greatly* simplifying the quoting.

Comment: Yes, but I used -i for that? I tried it and it works now, thanks to your explanation.

Comment: I find `-i` to be a bit pointless. `sed` is a **s**tream **ed**itor based on `ed`, designed to facilitate editing arbitrary streams of text rather than just files. If you are going to edit a file, go back to `ed` :)